# Ruby on Rails SSL Issue with Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, windows-10

I'm new to Ruby and following the course [Ruby on Rails Intro](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ruby-on-rails-intro/discussions) on course era and on the very first chapter installing software on Windows. After installing all the required software when the instructor asks me to run 'ruby new test_install'  get the following exception:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not verify the SSL certificate for
https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sqlite3-0.0.0.gemspec.rz.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see "bit.ly/ruby-ssl". To connect
without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

I should mention that I tried with gem -a sources http://rubygems.org but to no avail and I initially installed the rails 4.2.3 by giving it --source http://rubygems.org however nothing seems to work for this particular instance of command.

Comment: Windows has issues with Rails and Javascript. It is generally not worth while to try and troubleshoot them. I think you would be looking at a week of work attempting to set up your system. You are better off switching to Linux or Mac operating systems. They function much better. Linux even has a dual install option you can get working so you can run both linux and windows.

Comment: The quick answer is to remove the "s" from "https" in your Gemfile "https :// rubygems. org/"

Answer (score 1):

So far there's no fix for this that I can find.  It's not limited to Win10, either.  I've come across Win7 users with the same issue, so it seems to be a Rail on Windows problem.

There are also lots of Gemfiles.  It's not clear which one(s) need(s) to be changed.  I've tried changing  couple of them with no luck.

It does look like using Linux instead of Windows is the quickest way to a solution.  It might be worth giving that a try.  Other than the Mac-like weirdness of the Unity interface, Ubuntu is easy to get used to and VMWare Player is free.  I wouldn't bother with Virtual Box, the versions I've tried, including the latest, have been flaky.

If you do decide to try Ubuntu, you can find instructions here: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

That page recommends using MySQL or Postgres.  If you do use something other than SQLite (probably a good  idea, in which case Postgres is probably the better option), the creation of a new rails app requires setting the database at creation:
rails new myapp --database=postgresql
for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with this line:

`gem install bundler`

[Source:](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railsinstaller/wqPaK6TuNXY)

Comment: While it may not answer the question, it actually helped to solve my very similar problem. I was having various missing packages while trying to run `rails server` and was prompted to run `bundle install` which then was giving SSL errors. I could install each package individually, but adding the non-secure (http://rubygems.org) was not helping resolve the issue.

Little did I know, as a ruby/rails noob, that `bundle install` actually depended on bundler. `gem install bundler` solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem like this:

gem source -r https://rubygems.org/

gem source -a http://rubygems.org/

gem update